# How to use variable value in multiple views Laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

controller::

```
$states=$this->States->get_States();
$data=array('states'=>$states);
echo  View::make('frontend.list-property')->with('data', $data);
```

list-property.blade.php:: // this is sub view

```
@extends('layouts.frontend.frontend_login') 

@section('content')
<select>
  {{$states_drpdown}} //when I use this statement I am getting error

 </select>
 @stop
```

frontend_login.blade.php //This is layout file

```
   <?php
    $states_drpdown='';
    foreach ($data['states'] as $state):
    $states_drpdown.='<option value="'.$state->sid.'">'.$state->statename.'</option>';
endforeach
   ?>
    <select>
     {{$states_drpdown}}  //I am getting list of options here
    </select>
    @yield('content')
```

I am getting following error, can any one help me out pls.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also share a piece of data across all views:

```
View::share('name', 'Steve');
```

You can find more about this [here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views).

In your case, try: (*warning untested code*)

```
$states = $this->States->get_States();
$data   = View::share('states', $states);
return View::make('frontend.list-property');
```

Comment: Array of states are available in two views but $states_drpdown variable only coming in layout file not in list-property view

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array('states' => $this->States->get_States());
echo View::make('frontend.list-property', $data);
```

Assuming `$this->States->get_States()` returns a string of options, not an array?

```
<select>
    {{$states}}
</select>
```

If it `$this->States->get_States()` returns an array, you could just do this (no need for `<select>` tags):

```
{{ Input::select('name-of-field', $states, Input::old('name-of-field')) }}
```

Consider returning the view instead of echoing.

Comment: I am getting options if I use foreach statement in both the views But I want to use loop only one time because I am combining the views. I appriciate your answer.